# clear selections from recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i have `RecyclerView` with `longClick` and `click` method for every item,selecting item starts with a `longClick` and then single click allow user to select and as you see the background color of selected item will change,now i need one more things,when user pressed back Button i want to clear this selections and also background change to transparent,here is `RecycleViewAdapter`

```
public class Channel_Show_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Channel_Show_Adapter.ViewHolder> {


private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Channel_Show_Model> Data_1;
private static String TAG = "val";
public onLongClickInterface longClick;
public onClickInterface shortClick;
private boolean longClickDone;
private boolean shortClickActivated=false;


public Channel_Show_Adapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Channel_Show_Model> data, onLongClickInterface click1, onClickInterface click2) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.Data_1 = data;
    this.longClick = click1;
    this.shortClick = click2;
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener {


    AppCompatImageView image;
    TextView title, text, date, user;
    RelativeLayout singlePostLayout;



    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image = (AppCompatImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ch_msg_image);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ch_msg_title);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ch_msg_message);
        date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ch_msg_date);
        user = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ch_msg_user);
        singlePostLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channel_single_post_layout);


        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if(!shortClickActivated) {
            singlePostLayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blueTransparent));
            longClick.posClickedLong((short) getAdapterPosition());
            longClickDone = true;
            shortClickActivated=true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(longClickDone) {
            singlePostLayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blueTransparent));
            shortClick.posClickedShort((short) getAdapterPosition());
            shortClickActivated=true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Channel_Show_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.channel_show_recycler, parent, false);
    return new Channel_Show_Adapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Channel_Show_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(Data_1.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.text.setText(Data_1.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.date.setText(Data_1.get(position).getDate());

    if (Application_Class.userDataArray.get(0).isSuperAdmin() || Application_Class.userDataArray.get(0).isAdmin()) {
        holder.user.setText(Data_1.get(position).getUser());
    } else {
        holder.user.setText("");
    }
    Picasso.get().load(Data_1.get(position).getImage().getUrl()).noFade().into(holder.image);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Data_1.size();
}

interface onLongClickInterface{void posClickedLong(short p);}
interface onClickInterface{void posClickedShort(short p);}
}
```

and Activity

```
   @Override
public void posClickedLong(short p) {

    longClickOk=true;
    itemsTempArray.add(data.get(p).getId());

}
@Override
public void posClickedShort(short p) {

    itemsTempArray.add(data.get(p).getId());


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    backPressed=true;
    if(longClickOk && itemsTempArray.size()>0){
        longClickOk=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsTempArray.size(); i++)
                itemsTempArray.remove(i);

    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Add this to your model class :**

```
private boolean isSelected = false;
```

> **Create getter setter for the same in model class**

```
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
```

> **From your adapter for which position you want to select item:**

```
    holder.title.setTag(position);
    holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                int pos = (int) view.getTag();
                                setSelectedPosition(pos);
                            }
                        }
```

> **Method for selection**

```
    public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            list.get(i).setSelected(i == position);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

> **If you want to clear selection**

```
    public void clearSelection() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            list.get(i).setSelected(false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

> **You can call this methods from your parent fragment/Activity using adapter objects as well. Like you had coded using interface. Like below**

```
    @Override
    public void posClickedLong(short p) {
        adapter.setSelectedPosition(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void posClickedShort(short p) {
        adapter.setSelectedPosition(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    backPressed=true;
    if(longClickOk && itemsTempArray.size()>0){
       adapter.clearSelection();
    } else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

> **If you want to provide specific background for indication of selected/deselected state make a `selector drawable` like below named as *my_selector***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_shape_rectangle_border_orange" android:state_selected="true" />  // drawable to show when selected
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_shape_rectangle_border_white" /> // drawable for default state
</selector>
```

> **Code for `drawable_shape_rectangle_border_white`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:color="@color/white" />

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/_4sdp" />
</shape>
```

> set background to your layout

```
android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
```

> **in BindViewHolder**

```
holder.title.setSelected(model.isSelected()); // here I have tried changing background for your title view only. you can set these on your relative layout or any other needed layout.
```

Comment: thank you for reply,this code is working fine but i want to remove selected items background when back button pressed

Comment: you mean to say you are applying some sort of background to indicate status of selected and deselected right?

Comment: Welcome Mate!! Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

make boolean flag into your pojo class like in define above channel_show_model class define below code ..

```
    private boolean selectedFlag;


public boolean isSelectedFlag() {
    return selectedFlag;
}

public void setSelectedFlag(boolean selectedFlag) {
    this.selectedFlag = selectedFlag;
}
```

then after make two interface for handle longclick and single click like below code ..

```
 onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;
onItemLongClickListner onItemLongClickListner;

public void setOnItemLongClickListner(RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemLongClickListner onItemLongClickListner) {
    this.onItemLongClickListner = onItemLongClickListner;
}

public void setOnItemClickListner(RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

public interface onItemClickListner {
    void onClick(Channel_Show_Model str);//pass your object types.
}
public interface onItemLongClickListner{
    void onLongClick(Channel_Show_Model str);
}
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Channel_Show_Model data = mStringList.get(position); // if you pass object of class then create that class object.
    if(data.isSelectedFlag)
        holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListner.onClick(data);
        }
    });
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            onItemLongClickListner.onLongClick(data);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

then after in activity after bind adapter into recycler view used below code ..

```
recyclerViewAdpater.setOnItemClickListner(new RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(Channel_Show_Model str) {
            str.setSelectedFlag(true);
            recyclerViewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    recyclerViewAdpater.setOnItemLongClickListner(new RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemLongClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(Channel_Show_Model str) {
            str.setSelectedFlag(true);
            recyclerViewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

you can mange long click and single click take two boolean value.